# SwiftUI .task view modifier: in which thread does it run?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

SwiftUI has [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) `.task(priority:_:)` view modifier. It runs async code. The default priority is `userInitiated`. There are no mentions to which thread this runs on.

Just by testing seems that runs on background threads, but: is it safe to assume that always runs in a non-main thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure how you concluded that this was not on the main thread, but when I run it on a debugger, it is on the main queue:

[image]

And that makes sense, as [`body`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-8kl5o) is isolated to the main actor, and I would expect its `task` to run on behalf of the current actor (the main actor), too. (If you need to get something off the current actor, you would generally use a [detached](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) task. You only need to do that for slow, synchronous units of work, though.)

Bottom line, the SwiftUI `.task` view modifier for `body` is isolated to the main actor. (FWIW, I verified this empirically in a number of ways, too.)

In short, if you really need to make sure something is off the main actor (e.g., running something slow and synchronous within the `.task` view modifier), make sure to put that on a separate actor, within a detached task, or some equivalent pattern.

---

A few other observations:

1. As an aside, we no longer focus on threads within Swift concurrency. It can yield misleading results. Swift concurrency abstracts us away from thread-level reasoning. In the future, Swift 6 will remove many of these API that we used to programmatically query `Thread` information. Bottom line, stop worrying about threads and focus on actor isolation.

   If you really want to learn more about the Swift concurrency threading model, see WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/). It does not directly touch upon the `.task` view modifier question, but it will help you appreciate why we no longer focus on threads, like we once may have.
2. Personally, in my `.task` view modifiers, I am generally just calling some `async` method, and in that scenario, the actor used by the `.task` view modifier becomes largely irrelevant (because we just `await` that call, which suspends execution on the current actor, freeing it to go do other stuff).
3. Likewise, back in the GCD world, we wasted a lot of mental energy worrying if we were calling some particular method from the right queue (and dealt with runtime errors if we messed up). But in Swift concurrency, we isolate the called function to the appropriate actor and now we get compile-time warnings if we do not call it correctly (e.g., double-checking `Sendable` types when we use the “Strict concurrency checking” build setting of “Complete”, neglect to include a needed `await` when we cross actor boundaries, etc.).

---

In the comments, you mentioned that you were “checking the thread … inside the `async` function [called] from the task modifier”.

Yep, [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md), implemented in Swift 5.7, informs us that a non-isolated `async` functions “do not run on any actor’s executor”. So, unless it was a function somehow explicitly isolated to the main actor, it would not run on the main actor.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer.
When I was checking the thread I was doing it inside the async function I call from the `task` modifier, which makes sense once put together with your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about threading differently with async/await and the `.task` modifier. Although it begins on the main thread, each line of await code goes off and does something and when it completes it moves on to the next line. The actual thread that the awaited line runs on depends on its actor. If it is an async func inside the `View` struct then it is the main thread because that is marked with `@MainActor`, thus the main thread will be blocked during the await line. If it is declared in a different struct or class then it should be a random background thread. You can also get a background thread within the `.task` by using a child `Task { }` and even if the screen that is showing this View struct dissapears this child `Task` will still be cancelled same way `.task` is, be careful not to use `Task.detatched` because that will not be cancelled and could cause a crash. Another way to get a background thread in a `View` func is to mark it as `nonisolated`. Put a breakpoint inside this func to check it is on a background thread. Some classes or actors that do their async funcs in background threads use `MainActor.run` or `Task { @MainActor in` to switch to the main thread, e.g. to update an `@Published`. Not we don't need that any more with the new `@Observable` fetcher classes in Xcode 15/iOS 17, e.g.

```
@Observable
class Test {
    var counter = 0
    
    func update() async {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            counter+=1 // no longer need to wrap this in Task.mainActor { } to set this anymore
        }
        catch {
            
        }
    }
}
```